# Prevent Powershell Copy-Item to create sub dir in target when target folder exists

Tags: powershell

I am copying folders with

```
Copy-Item $source $target -Force -Recurse -Container -ErrorAction Stop
```

If $target folder already exists, sub folder will be created under $target with same name and files will be copied there. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `$target` already exists, and add a trailing `\*` to `$source` if it does, so that only the contents of the folder are copied, not the folder itself. Like this:

```
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $target) {
  $source += '\*'
}
Copy-Item $source $target -Force -Recurse -Container -ErrorAction Stop
```